# Webpack resolve/redirect file

Tags: cordova, webpack

I have this structure:

- **`src`**: Application files.
- **`src/index.html`** Main file of my application.
- **`src-cordova`**: Cordova-specifc files.
- **`src-cordova/config.xml`**: Cordova configuration file.

When I run Webpack server, it resolves `src/index.html` to `http://localhost:8080`. But I also need to resolve `src-cordova/config.xml` to `http://localhost:8080/config.xml`.

What is the best way to do it using Webpack?

**NOTE:** This is a Vue application, so I have the `vue.config.js` available to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to change your contentBase to here is an alternative.

In the vue.config.js add a chainWebpack to modify the CopyWebpakPlugin. This code will pick the destination from the first configuration in the CopyWebpackPlugin.

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  chainWebpack: (config) => {
    config
      .plugin('copy')
      .tap((args) => {
        const copyCordova = {
          from:  path.resolve(__dirname, 'src-cordova/config.xml'),
          to: args[0][0].to,
        };
        args[0].push(copyCordova);
        return args;
      })
  },
};
```

[Chaining Docs](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/webpack.html#chaining-advanced)

[CopyWebpackPlugin Docs](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/copy-webpack-plugin/)

Answer (score 0):

Set the `src-cordova` path as `contentBase`. This will serve static files. As per `webpack` [docs](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devservercontentbase):

```
module.exports = {
  //...
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'src-cordova')
  }
};
```